# ¿Como esperar X segundos para agregar un objeto en un arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy tratando de hacer un mini juego donde los enemigos spawnean al rededor del jugador, el problema es que salen muy rápido y  muy seguido y resulta muy difícil la jugabilidad, estos enemigos hacen parte de un arrayList de objetos "enemigos" y quería saber si hay algún método que me permita hacer mas lenta su aparición. Cabe aclarar que yo trate de hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

Clase EjecutarAccion:

```
public class EjecutarAccion implements Runnable{

boolean detenerEjecucion = false;

public void detenerEjecucion(boolean decision){
    this.detenerEjecucion = decision;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(!detenerEjecucion){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjecutarAccion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Clase dibujo - Método paint:

```
Thread hilo = new Thread(ejecutar);

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
    add(jugador);
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    jugador.dibujarJugador(g);
    jugador.disparar(g, bala);
    hilo.start();
    if (enemigos.size() <= 1) {
        enemigos.add(new Enemigo());
    }
}
```

Como pueden ver mi intencion es esperar 5 segundos entre el spawneo de cada enemigo. El problema de hacerlo de esta forma es que me pausa TODO el juego 5 segundos cada vez que destruyo un enemigo y se va a spawnear otro; por eso quería saber si existe una forma de hacer esto sin que afecte la totalidad del juego.

Comment: Para estos casos, es mejor un `Timer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que te parece un `java.util.Timer`?

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        enemigos.add(new Enemigo());
    }
}, 5000); //espera 5 segundos para a~adir un enemigo
```

NOTA: Si pones un `Timer` en paint, solamente verificando el `size` de el arreglo de el enemigo, resultará en una creación de un sin número de `Timers` hasta cumplir con los 5 segundos y el `enemigos.size` sea mayor o igual que 2

Estoy seguro que puedes encontrar un mejor sitio en donde poner este `Timer` o añadirle unas condiciones más a ese `if`como por ejemplo:

```
if(enemigos.size() <= 1 && !estaAnadiendoEnemigo ){
    estaAnadiendoEnemigo = true;
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            enemigos.add(new Enemigo());
            estaAnadiendoEnemigo = false;
        }
    }, 5000); //espera 5 segundos para a~adir un enemigo
}
```

**EDIT:**

Si lo que quieres es añadir un número específico de enemigos cuando `enemigos.size` sea <= 1, ejemplo:

> el jugador eliminó un enemigo y ahora solo queda 1, el programa tiene
>   que crear 10 enemigos más en un intervalo de 5 segundos

```
if(enemigos.size() <= 1 && !estaAnadiendoEnemigo ){
    estaAnadiendoEnemigo = true;
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int contador = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {                
            enemigos.add(new Enemigo());
            contador++;
            if(contador == 10){ 
                estaAnadiendoEnemigo = false; // terminó de añadir 10 enemigos
                cancel(); // cancelar el task para que no siga ejecutando
            }
        }
    }, 5000, 5000); //Nota que ahora hay dos números, tiempoAesperarParaEjecutar y intervaloEntreEjecuciones
}
```

Comment: He estado tratando de implementar este método, aun así creo que mi error esta en tratar de poner esto dentro de un método que lleve un repaint() en el, ya que como tu dices, es posible que este creando muchos hilos en una sola actualización. Trate de llevar el timer a la clase enemigo, pero tal como pensaba, el resultado es el mismo. Aun asi considero que el método que compartiste esta bien, mas el error esta en mi forma de escribir código.

Comment: @Smuk intentastes poner un campo `estaAnadiendoEnemigo`?

Comment: Ahora bien, mi respuesta solo va anadir un solo enemigo cuando la condición sea cierta, Si lo que quieres es añadir un número específico de enemigos cuando `enemigos.size sea <= 1`, edite la respuesta

Comment: Funciono a la perfección; Gracias!!.

Comment: Me quitaste la solución de la mano! jaja excelente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una clase que extienda desde Runnable y pasar como parámetro la función que quieras ejecutar o crearla dentro de esta clase. Despues creas un nuevo hilo y le pasas una instancia de la clase para ejecutarlo en "paralelo".

```
 public class EjecutarAccion implements Runnable {
 boolean detenerEje = false;

Thread hilo;

 public void detenerEjecucion(boolean a){
      this.detenerEje = a;
 }

  public void setHilo(Thread hilo) {
    this.hilo = hilo;
  }



 @Override
 public void run() {
    while (!detenerEje){
        System.out.println("accion!!!");
        try {
            this.hilo.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjecutarAccion .class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Esta clase se ejecutará cada 5000 milisegundos y la inicias como:

```
EjecutarAccion accionFoo = new EjecutarAccion();

Thread hilo = new Thread(accionFoo);
accionFoo.setHilo(accionFoo);  
hilo.start();
```

Después lo detienes con `accionFoo.detenerEjecucion(true);` porqué `hilo.stop()` es inseguro según la documentación. Esta manera deja que el proceso muera por sí solo.

Disculpa si el código está algo mal, me lo chute directamente en el foro. Cualquier cosa lo reviso pero ya en mi casa.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Por ahí me corrigieron muy amablemente. En realidad si se congelaba la pantalla porque estaba llamando directamente `Thread.sleep` que es el hilo principal del programa y por tanto se congela. Para evitar eso paso como instancia el nuevo hilo que se creó y lo guardo en una variable dentro de la clase `EjecutarAccion`. Después hago `this.hilo.sleep(5000)` y no se detiene el hilo principal.

**ACLARACIÓN**

Esta parte ocupas iniciarla de este modo:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        add(jugador);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jugador.dibujarJugador(g);
        jugador.disparar(g, bala);
        if (!hilo.isAlive()) {
            ejecutar.setArregloEnemigos(enemigos);
            hilo.start();

        }

    }
```

Y dentro del método `run()` de la clase `EjecutarAccion` pasas con un set el arreglo `enemigos` y lo vas haciendo crecer desde ahí de esta manera:

```
@Override
   public void run() {
        while (!detenerEje){
            if (enemigos.size() <= 1) {
                 enemigos.add(new Enemigo());
            }
            try {
                this.hilo.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EjecutarAccion .class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Implemente la clase he inicie el nuevo hilo dentro del método paint como dijiste, el problema es que obtengo una nueva excepción "IllegalThreadStateException", no sé si se deba a que tal vez este iniciando este nuevo hilo de alguna forma incorrecta, aun así el programa muestra solo un primer pantallaso del juego, y queda trabado, incluso aunque espere 5 segundos(mi error anterior pasaba de esa forma), no se si tal vez sepas algún modo "correcto" de iniciar este nuevo hilo dentro del método.

Comment: Actualiza lo que hiciste en tu pregunta para ver que es lo que tienes poder ayudarte por ese lado.

Comment: ¿Esta forma no congela toda la aplicación?

Comment: En efecto, toda la aplicación se congela.

Comment: @Smuk Es correcto. Una disculpa. Estoy editando la respuesta.

Comment: @Smuk ahora si. Prueba de nuevo con las modificaciones que hice. Estuve haciendo pruebas y a mi parecer debería funcionarte para lo que quieres.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ Completamente en lo cierto. Ya he corregido.

Comment: @Smuk Intenta a llamar el hilo fuera de `repaint()`  o pon una condición con `hilo.isAlive()`. De manera que si el hilo esta vivo no haces de nuevo `hilo.start()`

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero si pongo el condicional hilo.isAlive() que tendría que colocar dentro de ese condicional para que no se inicie un nuevo hilo?

Comment: @Smuk actualice la respuesta. Revisala y checa si te sirve.